# Проверка пересечения массивов на JavaScript - как?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, валидация

Есть некий интерфейс, где происходит разбиение русского алфавита на части (алфавитные группы букв):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

групп таких может быть сколько угодно, для этого есть кнопочка + добавить группу

Нужно реализовать функционал проверки на пересечение диапазонов алфавитных групп, т.е. на скриншоте выше показан верный пример разбивки, а вот этот уже неверный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

всё потому что в первой группе у нас диапазон букв от А до К, а во второй от той же К до T, таким образом вторая группа пересекается с первой по букве К

Как такой алгоритм проверки пересечения реализовать на JavaScript?

Comment: В полях могут быть только буквы?

Comment: В данном случае можно не проверять массивы, достаточно взять максимальные и минимальные элементы группы и проверить их с такими же элементами в соседней группе через `>` и `<`.

Comment: если вы по поводу option внутри select - то, можно в качестве value хранить там цифры - ключи массива из которого строятся значения для select

Comment: эврика! как же я сразу то не додумался! спасибо!

Comment: @AlexKrass, оформите ответ ответом?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, оформил как ответ.

Comment: Что должно выдаваться на следующее разбиение - **Н-Я, А-М**? Это не пересекающиеся диапазоны, но стоят не в алфавитном порядке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вашего случая не обязательно проверять полное вхождение, достаточно взять максимальные и минимальные элементы группы и проверить их с такими же элементами в соседней группе через `>` и `<`. При этом при использовании `<select>` эти значения у Вас уже есть изначально и остается только пройтись по ним и проверить.

```js
var validation = function(selectArray){
    for(var i=1; i<selectArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectArray[i].value <= selectArray[i-1].value) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
document.getElementById("process").onclick = function()
{
    var selectArray = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = validation(selectArray);
}
```

```html
    <div id="select">
        <select>
            <option>А</option>
            <option>Б</option>
            <option>В</option>
            <option>Г</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>А</option>
            <option selected>Б</option>
            <option>В</option>
            <option>Г</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>А</option>
            <option>Б</option>
            <option selected>В</option>
            <option>Г</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>А</option>
            <option>Б</option>
            <option>В</option>
            <option selected>Г</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="result">result</div>
    <button id="process">Проверить</button>
```

Встроенных средств в языке JavaScript нет, но есть способ определить вхождение элемента в массив через indexOf что упрощает задачу. Самый просто способ проверить вхождение одного массива в другой и элементы этого вхождения:

```
function Intersect(left, right) {
    return left.filter(function(el){
        return right.indexOf(el) != -1;
    });
}
```

Этот метод может быть не самым быстрым, для очень больших массивов в интернете выложены более эффективные методы.

Comment: В-Г, А-Б - два непересекающися диапазона, однако ваш код его выбраковывает

Comment: А-А, Б-Г - два непересекающихся, но тоже выбраковывает

Comment: @MiKeBu, да, все правильно, так и должно быть. Код заточен исключительно под этот конкретный случай, который не подразумевает неправильный порядок входящих групп в разметке или группы из одного символа.

Comment: А что скажете про Ё? В вопросе явно указан русский алфавит, где "ЕЁЖ", и по логике должно быть **Е < Ё < Ж**, однако в реальности **Е < Ё** и **Ж < Ё**, что не позволяет сравнивать буквы оператором`<=`

Comment: @MiKeBu, я же говорю, что не задавался целью писать универсальный вариант. Если надо решить задачу более универсальным способом, то мой ответ конечно не подходит, о чем и сказано изначально. Если нужно универсальное решение, то придется придумать что-то другое, как это сделали Вы. P.S. Хотя про "Ё" я забыл если честно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот моя реализация.

Работает с **произвольными последовательностями символов**, их порядок ("алфавит") задаете в переменной `alphabet`.

Как следствие - код способен обрабатывать русское **Ё**, украинские **Є** и **Ї**, а также прочие символы национальных алфавитов, находящиеся отдельно в таблице кодировки и при сравнении дающие непредсказуемый результат.

Под вашу задачу потребуется лишь собрать со страницы границы интервалов и отправить их на обработку в виде`[начало1,конец1, ... ,началоN,конецN]`, примеры найдете ниже в тестах.

```js
function checkIntersect(groups){
   groups=groups.map(function(e){return e.toLowerCase();});
   //alphabet - порядок символов алфавита
   var alphabet="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".toLowerCase(),
      correct=true;
   function diapazone(a,b){
      //ищем граничные символы и подстроку между ними
      var p1=alphabet.indexOf(a),
         p2=alphabet.indexOf(b),
         min=p1<p2 ? p1 : p2,
         max=p1<p2 ? p2 : p1,
         substr=alphabet.substring(min,max+1);
      if(p1<0 || p2<0 || substr.indexOf('-')>=0)
        return false; //не найден символ или внутри уже меняли - косяк
      alphabet=alphabet.replace(substr,'-'); //ставим метку о замене
      return true;
   }
   for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i+=2)//перебираем диапазоны
      correct = correct && diapazone(groups[i],groups[i+1]);
   return correct;
}

/*************Тесты*************/
function test(c){
   var res=checkIntersect(c);
   document.write(c[0]+"-"+c[1]+","+c[2]+"-"+c[3]+": "+res+"<br>");
}
test(["а","а","б","я"])//однобуквенный интервал
test(["а","м","н","я"])//типичные интервалы
test(["н","я","а","м"])//обратный порядок последовательностей
test(["я","н","м","а"])//развернутые последовательности
test(["а","е","ё","я"])//хитрая буква Ё
test(["а","я","м","н"])//включение одного интервала в другой
test(["а","н","м","я"])//пересечение двух интервалов
test(["а","м","н","z"])//не-алфавитные символы
```

Comment: Для чего в коде на константной строке toLowerCase() и переменная correct?

Comment: `correct` - переменная-результат, туда аккумулируем ошибки с помощью "логического и" (`&&` в коде). `.toLowerCase()` для алфавита - формальность, поскольку аргументы тоже приводим к нижнему регистру.

Comment: Хороший ответ, позвольте тогда еще немного поприставать)) 1. На константной строке `toLowerCase()` излишний. 2. Переменная correct не несет смысла, если `diapazone` вернул `false`, переменная больше не поменяется, дальнейший проход не имеет смысла. Можно смело выходить из `checkIntersect` с `return false` пропустив все остальные проверки и сэкономить время. 3. микрооптимизация: `substr = p1 < p2 ? alphabet.substring(p1, p2+1) : alphabet.substring(p2, p1+1);`

Comment: Спасибо) Насчет `correct`: ее единственное назначение - говорящее имя переменной. Она не для машины, а для людей